# LM393 comparator only connects to GND

Tags: comparator

I'm testing out the comparator LM393 but when I try and the comparator conditions meet 
it only outputs low and won't switch high.

That or I don't understand how it works properly so if you can help me out it would be great.

I have 2 power supplies (each independent.)

One output a voltage of 12V, the second can output 10V or 13V.

**Output 1** would resemble **V**ref (12v)

**Output 2** would resemble **V**in  (10-13V)

In the picture below

- **Vin** is connected to the non-inverting input
- **Vref** is connected to the inverting input
- **GND** is connected for both supplies
- **resistors** are for current limiting

The first diagram I've connected the led so when the comparator output switches low.

When only **V**in > **V**ref   it would light up.

---

In the second diagram I've connected the led so when the comparator switches high the LED will turn on

BUT no matter what the output won't switch high and the LED won't turn on.
What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: There **ARE** comparators that will pull high (as well as low). LM393 is **NOT** one of them - it only pulls low at its output pin.

Answer (score 5):

The LM393 has what's called an open collector output, as shown here from the datasheet.

This means the output can be pulled LOW when the BJT is turned on, but requires an external pull-up resistor to go HIGH when the BJT is turned off.

[image]

The typical applications section shows this pull up resistor:

[image]

Because of this, I recommend using your first circuit implementation.

Let me know if you have any follow up questions!

Answer (score 2):

You need a supply voltage that is higher than Vref by a couple volts. At 25°C, 1.5V is just enough to guarantee operation. From the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm393-n.pdf):

[image]

You can make it work by adding voltage dividers on each input, say equal value to R so that you get ~6V on each input.

Also note that the output is open-collector so your top circuit will work (with dividers), but for the bottom one use something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGyOaK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: isnt it supposed to be sensitive as 0.1V difference ?

Comment: ok i will try that thank you very much

Comment: You must keep the voltage at the inputs within the range 0V to V+-1.5V for it to work properly. That's what "Input Common Mode Voltage Range" means.

Comment: While it is important to observe the input common mode range, that typically just results in non-linear performance. It would not cause the problem AMD is seeing here.
@amdmoual, the comparator you have selected cannot output HIGH on it's own. It has an open collector output that can only go LOW. To output HIGH, there has to be an external pull up resistor on the output pin.

Answer (score 2):

**Always observe IC specs for Input and Output range.  Comparators are often open collector output so you swap inputs and use active low.**

### Other Design details.

When making a lead acid 12V battery voltage OK indicator , you want to start with specs.

e.g. Consider a threshold of  12V and a tolerance +/-5%  or below.

12.5 100% SoC   (after quick load or settling time)
 12.0V = 50% SoC
 11.5V = 0% SoC

SoC= State of Charge

Then you need a diode or voltage reference that can give you 1% accuracy which might be hard so you can consider any diode, even an LED or precision Zener or LDO.

[Here is one way](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%202%200.00039999999999999996%203.5993318835628396%2057%205%2050%0Aa%20288%20192%20432%20192%208%2012%200%201000000%201.5730060020340708%201.674815108951796%20100000%0Aw%20264%2080%20232%2080%200%0Aw%20288%20176%20232%20176%202%0Ar%20192%2040%20192%2080%200%2010000%0Ar%20128%20248%20128%20288%200%2010000%0Ag%20128%20288%20128%20304%200%0Ar%20128%20112%20128%20192%200%2068100%0AR%20128%2040%2096%2040%200%204%201%201%2012%200%200.5%0AO%20432%20192%20496%20192%200%0Ag%20192%20120%20192%20128%200%0A162%20192%2080%20192%20120%202%20default-led%201%200%200%200.01%0Aw%20192%2040%20128%2040%202%0Ap%20288%20208%20288%20176%201%200%0Ap%20264%2080%20264%2056%201%204%0Aw%20152%20208%20288%20208%202%0A403%20248%2096%20376%20160%200%201_64_0_28930_1.5747097975691193_0.0001_0_2_1_3%0Aw%20192%2080%20232%2080%200%0Aw%20232%20176%20232%2080%200%0Aw%20128%20112%20128%2040%200%0A403%20248%20272%20376%20336%200%2014_64_0_28930_1.701197693344473_0.0001_0_2_14_3%0A162%20432%2088%20432%20128%202%20default-led%201%200%200%200.01%0Aw%20192%2040%20432%2040%200%0Aw%20432%2040%20432%2088%200%0Ar%20432%20128%20432%20192%200%201000%0Ap%20288%20208%20288%20264%201%204%0Ap%20128%20112%2048%20112%201%204%0A403%200%2056%20128%20120%200%207_64_0_4354_20_0.1_0_2_7_3%0A174%20128%20192%20152%20224%201%201000%200.6485000000000001%20Resistance%0Aw%20128%20224%20128%20248%200%0Ao%207%208%200%2012546%2012.999539925957365%200.0001%200%202%207%203%0Ao%208%208%200%204098%2020%200.0000244140625%200%201%0A38%206%200%2050000%2080000%20Resistance%0A) using the same LED to scale down with a pot to adjust over the desire range only.

1) used an LED for Vref= 1.566V @1mA

2) Vcm input is suitable for some Op  Amps>1.5V

3) Choose R divider to scale down to Vref with care

4) Used 1k pot to reduce range control <2%

5) Simulated with 2Vpp ripple 11~13Vdc 1Hz

6) LED reduced to 18 mVpp ripple or <1% error

7) slider interactive adjustment on right

[image]